# Design of a broadband RF amplifier from 1 MHz to 5 GHz

Tags: amplifier, rf

Is there any broadband RF amplifier (AC-coupled) with 30 dB gain (maximum output > 30 dBm) that has flat response (max. 3 dB variation) from 1 MHz up to ca. 5 GHz? I checked several electronic sellers specialized on RF amplifiers, but unfortunatley they do not provide something like this. Can such a device be built, e.g. with a multi-stage design?

Comment: 1 MHz to 5 GHz is a 5,000:1 frequency range is sporty, to say the least.  Widest frequency range amps I've see without channelization have a 100:1 bandwidth.  And even those didn't meet your flat response requirement.

Comment: Plus, product recommendations are generally off limits here.

Comment: never mind the active devices in it, even the AC coupling will be tasty. 1 MHz needs a few nF. Try getting a cap that big mode-free to 5 GHz!

Comment: @Neil_UK, they're easy to get if you're willing to spend $5 per capacitor. Just google "broadband capacitor". The ones I know cover a few kHz up to 20 - 80 GHz.

Comment: Do you really want to design it yourself, or would you actually rather buy off the shelf? If you prefer off the shelf, check Marki Microwave, Mini-Circuits, and (if you want to spend a lot) SHF.

Comment: something as this ... need 2.  Good luck. https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/K2-ERA+.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It's overkill for your application, but *travelling-wave* amplifiers exist that operate from near-DC to over 20 GHz.

These are essentially multi-stage cascade amplifiers with transmission lines between the stages that match up the delay of the amplified signal with the delay of the input signal across the stages to achieve high gain over wide bandwidths.

The low-frequency cut-off is limited mainly by your ability to design a bias-tee to provide the power supply voltage to the output pin without shunting off the output signal.

You should be able to find these at RF chip vendors like Analog (former Hittite Microwave division) or Qorvo.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

> *Can such a device be build, e.g. with a multi-stage design?*

Yes, you can use parallel stages, each dealing with a band of frequencies and a final summing stage that needn't have gain hence could be made to be broadband quite simply.

Clearly you have to ensure that the "crossover" frequencies between the high-pass of one stage pays attention to the low-pass region of the next stage but, it's feasible.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @quantumphilip [please read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).